# How to draw bearing angle using leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I want to draw bearing angle using leaflet, as input I have a marker on map and the user can enter an angle value from a custom interface(this angle matches the bearing angle), so I want to draw this bearing angle on map. How can I do that on map using leaflet plugins? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found the solution, I used geodesy library from this link [https://github.com/chrisveness/geodesy ]

Comment: do you have a small sample please?

Comment: Sorry @André Fiedler for being late, I didn't pay attention to your comment. I used turf library which provides many geospatial analysis functions. Here is my code: var bearing = $('#BearingAngle').val();
        startpoint = new LatLon(latlngsMarker.lat, latlngsMarker.lng);
        var destBearing = start.rhumbDestinationPoint(distance_in_meter, bearing);
        var bearingLine = [startpoint, destBearing];
        var pathBering = new L.Polyline(bearingLine);